# Basic coroutine network call in a library

Tags: kotlin

I'm just reading and learning about coroutines in Kotlin to use in a small library for fun/learning purposes. In the documentation, you can do something like

```
GlobalScope.launch {

}
```

So in my method,

```
fun myMethod() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        // do some networking code
    }   
}
```

Is it best practice to use `GlobalScope` to launch a coroutine for a library? In the docs it says

> Application code usually should use application-defined CoroutineScope, using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is highly discouraged.

This is obviously a library and not necessarily app code. But I wasn't sure if that was the best way to do networking in the background with coroutines.

I also tried

```
runBlocking {
    async {
        // do some networking code
    }
}
```

Thinking that `runBlocking` introduces a new coroutine scope, but I think in this case it inherits the scope from its parents which is the main thread so then I get an exception about no networking on the main UI thread.

Comment: I would think a library should expose suspending functions and let the user handle the threading execution context for then, but who knows for sure.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce. Thanks. I was wondering if that was also a "best practice" of having the functions be suspending functions for the client to use as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a suspending function, and this will enforce that the user calls this from a coroutine themselves.
If your method uses `withContext` you don't have to worry about `GlobalScope` or configuring the scope. `withContext` simply tells the coroutine which context to use (for networking, you'll want `IO`. And the scope is determined now by however the user launches it.

The way I'd construct your method would be:

```
suspend fun myMethod() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // do some networking code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can use different patterns even inside a library.

If your function is supposed to **immediately return** after launching some coroutines, the "best practice" is to declare your function as an extension of the `CoroutineScope`, that way you don't have to use the global scope:

```
fun CoroutineScope.launchesAndReturnsImmediately() {
    // launch can be called because we are extending CoroutineScope
    launch {
        // some work
    }
}
```

That being said, you often **don't need to return immediately** when in a library, so you can declare your functions `suspend` instead, which is easier to grasp on the consumer side. Multiple options there:

- do some work in the background by using `withContext` to run on appropriate thread pool, or call other suspending functions
- use `coroutineScope` to launch child coroutines and decompose the work, but still suspend until all child coroutines are done
- "create" a suspension by wrapping callback-based asynchronous code, using `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`